# Redirect / replace URL Safari

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, safari, redux

For the life of me, I cant seem to figure this out (I'm sure I will kick myself once an answer gets posted and it works immediately)

I am trying to redirect a user once they click `Logout` (Sounds simple, I know). But this just refuses to redirect or go anywhere in `Safari 11`, it works in almost every other browser I have tested.

I am using `ReactJs` which will call an `action`. See code below:

**On the `JSX` page:**

```
    logout(e) {
    e.currentTarget.className += "preventDoubleClick";
    this.props.logout();
} //This pretty much just calls my action.
```

**Then my `action` looks like this:**

```
actions.logoutUser = function () {

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(actions.sendUserDataToSegment("Logout")); //Dont worry about me, im for tracking
        window.location.replace("/Auth/Logout");
       return Promise.resolve();

    }
};
```

Every article / forum I have read says that I should avoid using `window.location.replace` as this doesn't work, but everything I try to substitute it with, doesn't work either.

Pleaaaaassseeee help me, I am going insane with this simple thing. Also, let me know if I need to clarify anything further in this question.

**EDIT:** If I manually enter the `https://0edca8c6.ngrok.io/Auth/Logout` into the address bar on Safari, it hits my controllers and redirects :/

Thanks in advance for your time!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Use `history.push();` or `history.replace();` or `dispatch(push("url here"));`